# Is it "is" or "are" in this sentence?

Tags: grammar

for the sentence:

To remain competitive, the customization and personalization of industrial products is a growing concern for B2B companies.

Would you write it like this, or with "are growing concerns ..."?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> To remain competitive, the customization and personalization of industrial products is a growing concern for B2B companies.

In above sentence, there are **more than one concerns**.

Hence plural form should be used.

> To remain competitive, the customization and personalization of industrial products ***are growing concerns*** for B2B companies.

Comment: No. This has been done to death on ELU. Choice of verb-form depends on acceptance of notional agreement or not, and, if accepted, estimation of degree of cohesiveness of items joined by 'and' in the subject. 'Bacon and eggs is my favourite meal.'